# Page not found when saving product attribute in Magento admin

Tags: attributes, admin, product, magento2

When trying :

Stores > Attributes > Product > [product_attribute] values the page returns a 404 response.

the requested url turns into 
`admin/catalog/index/` instead of `admin/catalog/product_attribute`

Answer (score 2):

Finally after lot of debugging, solved this by increasing `max_input_vars` in `php.ini` from 1000 to 2000;